# Deck transformations and Gromov Hyperbolicity

Tags: reference-request, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces, hyperbolic-groups

I would like to ask, once more, for some references in Gromov-hyperbolic spaces. The question is specifically the following:

Does someone know any alternative reference, alternative proof, anything, about the results of chapter 8.1 of Gromov's book "Hyperbolic Groups: Essays in Geometric Group Theory"? To be more precise, I am looking for some more detailed exposition of the topics 8.2.H and 8.2.I therein.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks again for the support of the community.

The reference for the results I quoted here:
http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/olgak/gromov-hyp-grps.pdf